# Removal of a 2x4 with roof truss built on top

Tags: walls, structural, load-bearing

I am remodeling my bathroom and I have run into a problem removing some of the framing where a shower used to be. There is a 2x4 spanning the 5 1/2 foot width of the bathroom and it has been built into the top plate of the exterior wall and a roof truss sits on top of it. My question is can I get away with cutting it flush with the wall or should I just live with it and tile over it.

This 2x4 in question was a part of a wall that separated shower from vanity/bathroom. This shows the bathroom at a full view then a sketch of it. The walls are both load bearing. I have already removed one just like this on the far side near the toilet. All these walls that have been removed run parallel to the ceiling joists. Also there is an image of a spot where I removed a wall that created a shower surround and shows how the 2x4 was laid into the top plate of the wall.
[image]
[image][image][image]

Comment: impossible to imagine from the brief description ... please add a picture or a diagram

Comment: Sorry. Added photo. I have already taken out 2 others like this that were framed into the top plate but this one is the only one with a truss on it.

Comment: Bottom line, if that beam (or one of the others you removed) is load bearing it cannot be cut away. And it's hard to get to "Yes, cut out that beam" with this level of information. The picture helps a bit but I'm having trouble picturing the overall space and what has been removed. If you can draw a floorplan and an elevation indicating the location of the 3 beams (two already removed, one to go) that would help.

Comment: I suppose a more appropriate question would be what to do with this to make it the least noticeable as possible. I know removing it out from under the rafter is not an option. I thought about maybe cutting it flush though?

Answer (score 1):

Cutting it flush is the right solution. It's typical that double plates of intersecting walls interlock like that. There's nothing apparent to indicate that the plate continues to be structurally necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it was framed like the picture you posted, then yes, you can remove it without any structure compromise.